# Find out number of 2-cycle permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutation-cycles

I want to count all 2-cycle permutations of a set S = {1,2,3,4,..,n}.

After some calculations I came to following result:
$ \sum_{k=1}^{k=n-1} {n \choose n-k} * k!* (n-k)!$

I got this result by detection, that if n equals 4, then permutations are:

(123)(4) --> I have to choose 3 numbers into first permutation and permutate them and permutate the remaining one number.

(12)(34) --> I have to choose 2 numbers into first permutation and permutate them and permutate the remaining 2 numbers.

(1)(234) --> I have to choose 1 number into first permutation and permutate it and permutate the the remaining 3 numbers.

> Is this the right approach or I forgot some more permutations?

Comment: You seem to count the first type twice.  That is, the first and last type are the same.

Comment: Maybe adjust the upper limit to $n-2$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Something along the lines of $n/2$ is better I think, otherwise we have a lot of double counting if $n$ gets bigger.

Comment: Hmm, what is the same type of permutation? I mean, that permutation (1)(234) and (234)(1) isn´t the same ?!

Comment: It seems you leave out cycles that _aren't_ disjoint.

Comment: Yes, these are not included. I try to fix my formula.

Comment: What if I choose for the second time from the all elements and not only from which I didn´t choose before? $ \sum_{k=1}^{k=n-1} {n \choose n-k} * k!* {n \choose k} (n-k)!$

Comment: Are you sure that the problem doesn't ask for disjoint cycles?

Comment: The problem is listed as follows(translated): How many permutations of the set {1,2,...,n} with two cycles do exist? [EDITED]

Comment: That's different.  That's just $n!$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot something in the question

Comment: I edited the question once more.

Comment: 2-cycles are cycles with two elements (i,e, a swap), but you seem to be asking about permutations consisting ot two disjoint cycles (which may or may not be 2-cycles). And does a fixed element really count as a cycle?

Comment: I'm not sure what to do here.  Something seems to be lost in the translation.  Maybe they want the number of $2$-cycles.  That's just $n\choose2$.  Otherwise there seems to be some ambiguity.

Comment: Yes, now I understand what are you Jaap Scherphuis  and Chris Custer talking about. Maybe I made a mistake in translation. The problem asks for two disjoint cycles.

Comment: Ok.  Then try your original solution, but sum to $n/2$ to avoid double counting.

Comment: What happens if the n is odd ? Should I round up n/2 ?

Comment: Use the floor function.  Are you familiar with it?

Comment: Yes, I am. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were on the right track.  However, for a $k$-cycle, there are $k$ different ways to write it.  So dividing by $k$ will be necessary.

Also, your original formula double counts.  For, disjoint cycles commute.

Adjusting, we get $\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{n\choose k}(k-1)!(n-k-1)!$.

Comment: Doesn't this still double count the case when $n$ is even and $k=n/2$? It would be better to let the sum go up to $n$ and divide by 2.